# How to generate data that have given conditional mean and conditional quantile using R?

Tags: r, regression, simulation, conditional-expectation, quantiles

Suppose I want to generate independent data $(y_{i},x_{i})$ such that the conditional mean of $y_{i}$ given $x_{i}$ is a quadratic function in $x_{i}$ and the $.25$ conditional quantile of $y_{i}$ given $x_{i}$ is a function different than the conditional mean function.

I can generate such data with the given conditional mean using R. But how to make the $.25$ conditional quantile function different than the regression function?

Comment: I might be missing the point, but wouldn't $y_i =x_i^2 +\epsilon_i$ where $\epsilon_i$ is normal with mean 0, do the job?

Comment: I am a bit unclear what exactly you require of the quantile. You could follow the advice of @Cettt and draw the noise terms from a normal distribution with a variance that depends on $x_i$, e.g., $\epsilon_i\sim N(0,x_i^2)$, then the quantiles will depend on $x_i$ not only through the mean.

Comment: Hi. Thank you all for the useful info. That gave me something to begin with. Thanks. I guess I worked out what I want. Thanks. @StephanKolassa,@Cettt

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach would be to draw $X\sim U[0,1]$ and $Y\sim N(x^2,x)$, i.e., the variance of $Y$ is $x$. Then the $0.25$ quantile of $Y$ would be $z_{0.25}\sqrt{x}$. Here are simulated data, with the expectation as a black and the quantile as a red line:

[image: plot]

R code:

```
set.seed(1)
xx <- runif(1e3)
yy <- rnorm(length(xx),xx^2,sqrt(xx))
plot(xx,yy,pch=19,las=1,cex=0.6)

xx_pred <- seq(.01,.99,by=.01)
lines(xx_pred,xx_pred^2,lwd=2)
lines(xx_pred,qnorm(0.25,xx_pred^2,sqrt(xx_pred)),col="red",lwd=2)
```